SQL Server Management Studio 20 - Server name - . (dot) - no inicia con el dot
sin mucho rodeo, acabo de instalar el Microsoft SQL server Management Studio 20 en mi laptop y al momento de iniciar mediante el server name, no puedo iniciar con el dot(.). Recuerdo que en mis clases de instituto se iniciaba con el dot. Quiero saber el porque se iniciaba con el dot y porque no puedo hacerlo en mi laptop.
Se puede iniciar y continuar, en eso no hay problema. Solo quiero saber el porque del dot y porque no puedo entrar en mi laptop mediante el uso del dot. Gracias.

¿Da error? Si sí, ¿cuál error? Pulsa en [edit] y agrega más detalles a tu pregunta.

El punto como nombre de servidor es para referirse al servidor local y por lo tanto a la instancia default. Si no está instalado el servidor de SQL Server o no están corriendo los servicios o no está configurado correctamente, obtendrás un error al conectarte.
Si solo instalaste Management Studio, necesitas instalar el servidor de SQL Server. Puedes utilizar las ediciones gratuitas como Developer (versión completa para aprendizaje, desarrollo o pruebas) o Express(versión limitada para ambientes productivos) desde la página de Microsoft.
